# Retangle referencing canvas width exceeds canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas

I am trying to draw a retangle inside a canvas width rounded corners, when I give this hardcoded the same size as the canvas it shows up perfect.

However when I use these lines to reference parent for width and height:

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner, Path=ActualHeight}"
Width="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

The right and bottom will exceed the canvas, I have attached a picture of the behaviour.

[image: Retangle exceeding width]

Anyone can give me a hint what is going wrong here?

**Edit**

The canvas xaml is:

```
<s:DesignerCanvas Focusable="true" x:Name="MyDesigner"
                        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                        FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                        ContextMenu="{StaticResource DesignerCanvasContextMenu}"
                              Width="300" Height="300">
                <Rectangle
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        Fill="Transparent"
                        Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"
                        RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"
                        Canvas.Left="0"
                        Canvas.Top="0"/>
                <Thumb Name="myThumb" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="0" Background="Blue" 
                  Width="10" Height="10" DragDelta="onDragDelta" 
                  DragStarted="onDragStarted" DragCompleted="onDragCompleted"/>
            </s:DesignerCanvas>
```

The difference is when I change width and height of the retangle to 300 it fits perfectly.

DesignerCanvas, is a class that inherits canvas with few extra functions.

Comment: can you show the rest of your XAML code, or even better the 2 variants?

Comment: Why dont you use `Border`? As for your question - my wild guess is: your rectangle has some kind of offset (due to margin or padding or top left corner postion). You should post your xaml.

Comment: I have editted my post and added the xaml, I don't use border because later on I want to add adorners to the retangle and draw lines to elements that are going to be inside of the retangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the rectangle is initially drawn (bigger) and then resized to fit the `Canvas` (which is smaller or became smaller after the whole app was resized to fit the design). But `Canvas` will never do automatic resize (repaint) of it's children for you which means the changed shape won't show up or redraw itself. It will always show shapes exactly how the look like at the moment when added to the canvas's children.

If you want automatic resize you should choose a `Grid` or `StackPanel` as a host instead of the `Canvas` and set the rectangle's dimensions to `Auto` or it's `Stretch` property to 'Fill'. The grids will auto invalidate themselves and then redraw all contents.

Check the remarks of [MSDN - Canvas Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx). It's explained here...

Alternatively bind the `Canvas.Children` to a collection of your rectangles. You would then update rectangle dimensions to `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` whenever the `Canvas.SizeChanged` event is raised...or manually remove the old rectangle from the `Canvas.Children` collection and then add the resized one again.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I already had a resize for the canvas with the small dot in the bottom right corner. I now added the resize for the retangle there as well and works like a charm.